# .NET HttpClient GET request very slow after ~100 seconds idle

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dotnet-httpclient

The first request or a request after idling roughly 100 seconds is very slow and takes 15-30 seconds.  Any request without idling takes less than a second.  I am fine with the first request taking time, just not the small idle time causing the slowdown.

The slowdown is not unique to the client, if I keep making requests on one client then it stays quick on the other.  Only when all are idle for 100 seconds does it slowdown.

Here are some changes that I have tried:

- Setting **HttpClient** to a singleton and not disposing it using a using() block
- Setting **ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime** to a higher value since by default it is 100 seconds.  Since the time period is the same as mine I thought this was the issue but it did not solve it.
- Setting a higher **ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit**
- Default proxy settings set via web.config
- using **await** instead of **httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result**

It is not related to IIS application pool recycling since the default there is set to 20mn and the rest of the application remains quick.

The requests are to a web service which communicates with AWS S3 to get files.  I am at a loss for ideas at this point and all my research has led me to the above points that I already tried.  Any ideas would be appreciated!

Here is the method:
`

```
//get httpclient singleton or create
var httpClient = HttpClientProvider.FileServiceHttpClient;
var queryString = string.Format("?key={0}", key);

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, queryString);

var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{

    var metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var header in response.Headers)
    {
        //grab tf headers
        if (header.Key.StartsWith(_metadataHeaderPrefix))
        {
            metadata.Add(header.Key.Substring(_metadataHeaderPrefix.Length), header.Value.First());
        }
    }

    var virtualFile = new VirtualFile
    {
        QualifiedPath = key,
        FileStream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result,
        Metadata = metadata
    };
    return virtualFile;
}
return null;
```

Comment: Do you have a code sample to give us more of what you're working with?

Comment: updated the OP to add the code

Answer (score 0):

The default idle timeout is about 1-2 mins. After that, the client has to re handshake with the server. So, you will find that it will be slow after 100s.

You could use socket handler to extend the idle timeout.

```
var socketsHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler
{
      PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(27),//Actually 5 mins can be idle at maximum. Note that timeouts longer than the TCP timeout may be ignored if no keep-alive TCP message is set at the transport level.
      MaxConnectionsPerServer = 10
};
client = new HttpClient(socketsHandler);
```

As you can see, although I set the idle timeout to 27 hours, but actually it just keep 5 mins alive.

So, finally I just call the target endpoint using the same HttpClient every 1 min. In this case, there is always an established connection. You could use netstat to check that. It works fine.